# Google's 20th Anniversary: Make 20 using 6 0 0 6 1 3

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Belated 20th Happy Birthday to Google (600613)!

> Challenge: Use 6, 0, 0, 6, 1, 3 to make the number 20.

**Rules:**

- Use all numbers, in that exact order.
- Allowed operations: +, -, x, /, sqrt, (); no factorials, nth roots or powers
- No concatenation of final result (e.g. 2 || 0) but concatenation allowed for original numbers
- All numbers in base 10.

Comment: Are we allowed to use powers?

Comment: @WaisKamal Nope, only basic arithmetic operations and a square root.

Comment: Which bases can i use? Is it allowed to use the ternary system?

Comment: I'm a fool! Haha. Okay I think the easiest is noticing that 20 is the square root of 400, this is the third solution in the accepted answer.

Comment: ....Why is it 600613 instead of 900913? =/ 9 looks much more like a g. 900913 is even an unofficial code for the Web Mercator map projection (the one used by their maps and that quickly dominated the industry for display purposes) after them.

Comment: @jpmc26 G = 6 is closer than it is to 9

Comment: Yes, G=6, but g=9 :) So the number should be 600913.

Comment: sqrt(600/6) x sqrt(1+3)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about

> $\frac{60}{0+6-1\times3}$

another one

> $60\times(0\times6+\frac{1}{3})$

last one

> $\sqrt{\frac{600}{6}\times(1+3)}$

Comment: (+1) that was quick! I'll wait for more answers before ticking :)

Comment: The first one evaluates to 30, not 20.

Comment: @WaisKamal I think it is still 20. You may want to check it again.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry for that :)

Comment: This is one of the few types of problems where $\div$ actually looks better than the fraction; it makes the sequence of inputs more obvious.

Comment: I got exactly 20 likes, this should be a sign!

Comment: @Oray Do you want me to undo my upvote? ;)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution:

> $\frac{60 + (0 × 6 × 1)}3 = 20$

Answer (score 8):

How about:

> -(60-0)/6*(1-3)

I rolled back the MathJax edit as, although it looks prettier, I feel that the in-line solution is required to precisely meet the "in that exact order." requirement.

Comment: answers need to be of a certain length to be posted

Comment: This is basically the same as JonMark Perry's (second) solution.

Answer (score 6):

Not quite an answer, but a kind of lateral (or *literal*) thinking one

> $6\times0+\frac{x}{x}+0+6+13$ (assuming $x$ non-zero)

It's because

> *Allowed operations: +, -, x, /, sqrt, ();* so, x is allowed (despite it's used as a variable, not operation; there is definitely a lowercase x, not a multiplication sign in the question text)

Comment: Nice thinking, but you use both `x` and `✕`.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

> $6-0^0+(6-1)\times3$.

Without a power:

> $\frac{60+0}{6}\times(-1+3)$

Comment: "no factorial" it seems.

Comment: @oray; thx, I'll go with 0*0 (I assume this is power?)

Comment: I have no idea what * is :)

Comment: Sorry, no powers!

Comment: @TheSimpliFire; what does * do then?

Comment: Whoops that was a duplicate of x

Comment: Isn't $0^0$ not really well-defined?

Comment: @LegionMammal978; don't know - it doesn't matter anymore here, you can see https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node14.html for a list of arguments.

Comment: @LegionMammal978: Raising a number to an whole-number power is defined in terms of multiplication, just as multiplying by a whole-number factor is defined in terms of addition.  The former operator yields the multiplicative identity when the power is zero, and the latter always yields the additive identity when the whole-number factor is zero.  Algebraic fields may define their own "power" operator which allows raising things to powers which are not multiples of the multiplicative identity, but lose the ability to raise certain items to the zero power.

Answer (score 5):

I wonder why this very obvious solution has not yet been mentioned:

> (60+0×61)/3

It's only 11 characters long. I doubt you can make it any shorter.

Comment: Even though this exact solution hasn't been mentioned, it is almost the same as xhienne's.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

> $-(6^0+0-6)(1+3)$

edit new one without power:

> $\frac{\sqrt{600\times6}}{(1\times 3)}$

Comment: Great answer, but sorry, no powers! :)

Comment: ah I thought it meant you can't square the number as in you can't add another number. new one should do the job

Answer (score 4):

> How about $\sqrt{600/6}\times\sqrt{1+3}$?

Comment: Nice. Note that @Oray has already got that one :P

Comment: Heh. I thought I checked them all before posting. Hmmm... wait, that's a subtly different solution (assuming we're looking at the same). He's taking the square root of 400, I am multiplying 10 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

a very simple way to go would be-

> $6+0!+0+6+1+3!=20$

Comment: No factorials :P

Comment: oh, missed that, sorry.